# Some of WPF functionalities does not work on another computer

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp, desktop-application

We've developed a desktop application using .NetFX3.5 which has some winforms and two WPF windows. **I've installed it on almost 20 different computers (most of them have XP) and all are working fine except for three PCs** (which also have XP and relatively new hardware specs).

Here is the situation:

- `WPFWindow1` contains some buttons with click events (which all work fine), and a `ProgressBar` which reads from a list and generates some UIElements for each of them (the creation of these UIElemets use both **binding approach** and **classic child adding approach**.
- `WPFWindow2` contains a help button with a click event (which works fine) and a `ComboBox` (which only *populates its items* correctly).

And the problem:

- When I open `WPFWindow1`, the `ProgressBar` does not start although it's provided with the proper objects to read from.
- And in `WPFWindow2`, when I select an item form `ComboBox` I expect it to show its reports below the ComboBox but it doesn't show anything.

I've installed .NetFX4 on all target computers. maybe another assembly or update is missing?
or something wrong with permissions (this is a high security site and we use some strict  policies with symantec endpoint protection)

Any help, advice, suggestions, insight or else is greatly appreciated.

---

When WPFWindow2 is loaded the following timer starts:

```
void delayTimer_Elapsed(...)
{
    delayTimer.Stop();
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker(
        delegate{
            foreach(var data in dataList)
            {
                MyWpfControlList.Add(new MyWpfControl(data));
                progressBar.Value++;
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }));
}
```

---

Edited: I'm not sure where this issue is coming from. But since it's working almost everywhere, **I don't think** it would be related to the code.

Could it be a windows update?

Comment: The Systems on which the problem occurs are 32-bit or 64-bit. Sometimes this sort of incompatibility between development system and user system yields different results

Comment: They are all 32bit, and there's a laptop (64bit win7) which also works fine.

Comment: I had a similar problem years ago which turned out to be one of the host intrusion / memory protection modules in the Mcafee AntiVirus suite - it was just breaking .NET apps in all kinds of inexplicable ways. 

My issue was resolved with a Mcafee update - the problem machines were on a very old version - but diagnosed by disabling it. 

Since then pretty much the first thing I do when faced with random machine-specific problems is try to disable all the security software and go from there.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't the issue this time, but I'll keep that in mind:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress bar is showing a background task is that correct? If so is the background task executed on a background thread or on the UI thread? If the UI then you may find that some computers (ie: those with 1 CPU or low powered CPUs) the message pump is unable to update the progress bar as your CPU is being used largely for the list update. If this is the case what you need to do is to execute your background task on a thread and update the progress bar periodically using Dispatcher.Invoke to marshal the updates onto the UI thread.

Please can you post a code example so we can take a closer look? Otherwise its just guesswork!

Best regards,

Comment: The progress bar works in the same thread as the wpf window. it's as simple as a loop with `Application.DoEvents()` at the end of it.

Comment: Application.DoEvents() will have no effect on WPF as it uses a different message pump to WindowsForms. What you really need to do is put the work on a background thread and update the progress bar using the Dispatcher

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I will try it as you said:-)

Comment: And by the way, in the loop I am creating wpf custom controls. so I need to invoke them from Dispatcher or something like this, no? doesn't this approach cause the same problem?

Comment: Thanks for the precise info. It seems the `delayTimer_Elapsed` does not run due to an incompatibility of `System.Timers.Timer`. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` does not work either for the same reason and when I use `DispatcherTimer` a `MissingMethodException` is thrown. I'm cutting off the `delay_timer` for now, and I'll post the results as soon as I test the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the minimum and maximum values on the progress bar ? is the maximum greater than minimu

Comment: Yes but as I said, it's currently working on several PCs. I'm looking for some sort of a requirement's mismatching version or update or a registry trick or a missing windows component...